# How to pass *args to Mongoid pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using MongoiId have following code:

```
def self.sort_by_fields(*args) 
    .....Other stuff...... 

    pluck(args) 

    .....Other stuff......  
end
```

I am not able to do

```
Model.sort_by_field("id", "account", "name")
```

because `args` is an array and `pluck` in Mongoid don't take array.
Please suggest possible solution.
I want to pass arguments to `pluck` method so that I can get specific fields only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `*` to the other `args`

```
def self.sort_by_fields(*args) 
    .....Other stuff...... 
    pluck(*args) 
    .....Other stuff......  
end
```

Comment: blow up mind, great!